# How to capture expression inside a balanced strings match in lua

Tags: lua, pattern-matching, capture, gsub

I want to use `gsub` in lua to transform expression like this :

```
MACRO(part1, part2)
```

in this :

```
part1SOMETHINGpart2
```

with `SOMETHING` depending on `part1` and `part2`.

So I could use something like :

```
line = (string.gsub(line, "MACRO%((.-), *(.-)%)", "%1SOMETHING%2"))
```

and multiplying the line for putting some conditions on the two parts captured, for handling the different cases.

The problem is that part1 or part2 can contain macros :

```
MACRO(MACRO(a,b),c)
```

so the expression above will not match the good parenthesis...

I know there is in lua the possibility to match balanced parentheses with %b() but as far as I know we can't put condition on the inside and we can't use capture as I have done above.

Do you know a way to achieve what I want to do ?

Comment: From what I understand, you're better off by creating your own module/class.

Comment: You should have a look at [LPeg](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/); just a hint as you explicitly requested a solution with `gsub`

Answer (score 1):

You need to do all replacements:

```
local oldline,line
line=[[
MACRO(MACRO(a,b),c)
]]
repeat
    oldline,line=line,line:gsub("MACRO%((.-), *(.-)%)", "%1SOMETHING%2")
until oldline==line
print(line)
```

However, this is a hack because, despite appearances, it does not expand macros in the correct order since it does not really identifies macro calls and arguments correctly.

Since the expression in `line` is valid Lua code, try also this solution, which will perform as expected, since the Lua parser will do all the hard work:

```
a="A"; b="B"; c="C"
function MACRO(a,b) return "["..a..","..b.."]" end
line=[[
MACRO(MACRO(a,b),c)
]]
print(load("return "..line)())
```

Of course, define `MACRO` as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But in fact MACRO can be in the middle of the line, because the input is a C file and the MACRO I want to remove is a C MACRO...

Comment: @user2299676, if you give a concrete example, I might be able to give you a better solution. Perhaps post a separate question on macro expansion using Lua?

Comment: Well thank you very much for your help, finally doing macro expansion with lua did not seem to be a good idea so I solve my problem differently. But it is frustrating because matching balanced parentheses is a powerful tool, but it seems that we can't exploit all its power here.